# Controlling tabbing in form inputs

Tags: html, tabs, tabindex

is it possible to skip the url field when tab button is pressed in a form?
like after it goes to the last input element i wanted it to go back to the first input element instead of going to the url field!

thanks a alot.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `onkeyup` on your last input and check if the tab-key was pressed and then run something like `your_first_input.focus()`, so that it jumps to the first input.

Comment: hi! i tried adding the onkeyup but it doesnt stay on the last_input element for long, like it goes directly to the your_first_input element. it just kind of passes. it does not rest on the last_input element is what i mean..

Comment: did i miss out on something with the onKeyup event?

Comment: You have to make a function that checks if the tab key is pressed and only then trigger the focus().

Comment: if you are on the 2nd last input, press tab, it change focus to the last, and then you relese the tab and trigger the onkeyup, so try onkeydown insted